# Integration testing indexing operations

Tags: algolia

I am writing an integration test where `.saveObject()` is called and then I check that the object was indexed properly.

What is the correct method of integration testing Algolia? What is the correct method of waiting for the indexing operation to succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we don't have an official recommendation for making integration tests specifically. However, you can use the [saveObjects](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/update-objects/) method, get the taskID from the result and then use the [waitTask](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/wait-task/) method to make sure that the operation is completed.

Comment: I can confirm for others that this is a working method of integration testing Algolia. Hope you guys consider officially supporting it.